# Please tell me how to write sql query to seacrh smart account number input format

Tags: sql

1. User types first three digits of product code and account number without prefix zeros
2. System automatically converts it into full account number in collection, transaction screen

Example:

Account Number: 00200600000123

User Types: 006123

```
002 - Branch Code
006 - Product Code
00000123 - Account Number
```

As the system already knows the login branch code, it adds 002 and adds zero prefix to account number

Comment: What does smart account number stand for?

Comment: Hi Pratik, Welcome to SO. what is your table structure and expected output ? Please check https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Smart account number means i will type half account number it shoul give me entier number

Comment: Check `LIKE` operator. If you know the number of input string use `SUBSTR`

Comment: What is your question? What specifically do you need help with? Do you need help with converting 006123 to 00200600000123 or do you need help with database searching? If you need help with database searching please provide sample data and sample search string.

Comment: Sample data is  below                                                                                                                    Example:

Account Number: 00200600000123

User Types: 006123

002 - Branch Code
006 - Product Code
00000123 - Account Number i will only type product code ie 006 and account number 123 measn i will just type 006123 so the output should find entier number 00200600000123

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to generate the smart number from the branch table using branch_code and user_input

```
  SELECT branch_code ||substr(:user_input,1,3)||lpad(substr(:user_input,4),9,0)
  FROM branch_table
   where branch_code=global.current_branch;
```